# Connection to Windows server using .Net

Tags: asp.net, windows-server-2008-r2

Can I use Renci.SshNet library to connect to Windows server 2008 r2 to perform start/stop of any script?

If yes than how? And if not what is another way?

Comment: What is `Renci.SshNet`?

Comment: @PatrickHofman: http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/SSH.NET/Renci.SshNet/Renci.SshNet

Comment: Have you read the documentation on https://sshnet.codeplex.com/?

Comment: I didn't get ans. Please help